# Where to apply to become a Jedi knight?

Tags: star-wars, jedi, jedi-training

Can you become a Jedi knight if you wanted to? Will the academy accept applications or they only choose for themselves?

Comment: apply here :) http://newyorkjedi.com/

Comment: I would imagine you could apply, but you're probably too old, yes too old to begin the training.

Comment: Even if I have lots of passion? Can't something like in [Invincible](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0445990) where age is overcome happen? Oh I don't think the Sith have any such qualms. They respect talent.

Comment: Passion probably wouldn't help you get in to Jedi training, path to the dark side and all, maybe if you had [Benjamin Button](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0421715/) disease...

Comment: Representatives from their Training Academy make annual visits to Orlando, FL.  I'd start there.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It depends on the era.

Before the execution of Order 66, The Jedi routinely checked the children of the republic for acceptable levels of midiclorians (SWI:TPM). Once a candidate was identified the Jedi would offer to train the child and, if necessary, use the Jedi Suggestion to get permission.  These children would be brought to the academy and trained from an early age so that they would not remember their parents or form an attachment.

After RotJ, Luke reestablished the order. In doing so he recruited many adults and even married couples into the new Order.  It was no longer necessary for children to be pried from their parents' arms and the Order even provided lodging for families of young jedi.  The new Order was willing to train anyone who showed any force talent at all, including many that likely would not have met the midichlorian count that was required by the original Jedi Order.  As for where, most applicants came to the Jedi Temple on Coruscant.  However most were still discovered by Jedi in the field though through the force rather than using midichlorian count.

Comment: The old Order did take babies in for later training, but do you have any evidence they stole them like that?

Comment: @Kevin - I do not have a specific book but it was in NJO.  [Vergere](http://starwars.wikia.com/wiki/Vergere) told jacen about it.  I suppose its possible she was lying but I do not think that there would have been any upside to making that up.  I would have to reread half of the series to find the specific quote... and I dont have any of that series on ebook.

Comment: Acceptance into the order does not imply path to Knightdom does it? Isn't the council alone responsible for granting the title of Jedi Knight?

Comment: @Josh I was answering the question that was asked in the text which is what I assume he actually meant with his Title question.  But yes to become a knight you have to be promoted by your master or a member of the council. Unless you are the sole remaining jedi known to the galaxy then I guess you can promote your self to master at will(Luke claimed he was a jedi master in Jabba's palace)

Comment: Isn't Luke's new Jedi Temple in the Sith ruins of Yavin IV, rather than Corruscant?

Comment: @TZHX - There is one there too, as well as one in the Maw.  But the council meets on Coruscant and most of the masters reside on Coruscant... at least when they can... but no more spoilers.

Comment: @Chad - Luke did not claim to be a Jedi Master in Jabba's palace. He said "Greetings exalted one, I am Luke Skywalker, Jedi knight and friend of captain Solo....". Luke only said he was a Jedi Master several years later after defeating the ressurected emperor when he petitioned the New Republic to sanction his search for Jedi candidates to rebuild the order that he was officially recognized as the last Jedi Master. Luke seemed to genuinely believe that he was a Jedi in Jabba's palace. It wasn't until he went back to Dagobah that Yoda told him he wasn't a Jedi untilhe confronted Vader again.

Comment: @JediWitness - That was in the recording.  When he came to confront Jabba in person he said he was a Jedi Master. I have no idea if he believed that or if it was a bluff.

Comment: @Kevin There's an entire "story arc"(?) in the Clone Wars TV show (Disney Canon) regarding force sensitive children.

Comment: @Anoplexian - Yeah this answer was written before them.  This answer could be considered legacy now

Comment: @Chad Nah, they started the series in 2008, so there'd be at least 2 if not 3 seasons already made.

Comment: @Anoplexian the stories you are taliing about are from 2012 after this question and answer https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_Star_Wars:_The_Clone_Wars_episodes#Season_5_.282012.E2.80.9313.29

Comment: @Chad The episode is actually Season 2 Episode 3.